# Unknown solution item type: {42C0BBD9-55CE-4FC1-8D90-A7348ABAFB23}

Tags: c#, macos, mono, monodevelop, monomac

I am trying to open [a project](https://github.com/OpenDataSpace/CmisSync/blob/gds2-master/CmisSync/Mac/CmisSync.csproj) in Monodevelop (3.0.5, with MonoMac add-in enabled) on Mac Mavericks.

I get this error:

```
MonoDevelop.Projects.Formats.MSBuild.UnknownSolutionItemTypeException: Unknown solution item type: {42C0BBD9-55CE-4FC1-8D90-A7348ABAFB23};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.Formats.MSBuild.MSBuildProjectHandler.CreateSolutionItem (IProgressMonitor monitor, MonoDevelop.Projects.Formats.MSBuild.MSBuildProject p, System.String fileName, System.String language, System.String typeGuids, System.String itemType, System.Type itemClass) [0x00143] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-monodevelop-3.0-series/e159cf08/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Projects.Formats.MSBuild/MSBuildProjectHandler.cs:369
```

The most relevant part is probably this one:

> Unknown solution item type: {42C0BBD9-55CE-4FC1-8D90-A7348ABAFB23};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}

These UUIDs can be found in the `<ProjectTypeGuids>` of the `.csproj` file I try to open.

- `FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC` is the UUID for C# projects,
- `42C0BBD9-55CE-4FC1-8D90-A7348ABAFB23` is the UUID for MonoMac projects.

I can open other C# projects normally, so I guess this is a problem with Monomac?

Monodevelop has the MonoMac add-in enabled. I tried to compile MonoMac from source but the DLL it generates can't be loaded as an add-in (`ZipException`).

Comment: MonoDevelop 3 is very old; I recommend you to compile MonoDevelop4.x yourself

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The solution was to remove the following line from the `.csproj` altogether:

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{42C0BBD9-55CE-4FC1-8D90-A7348ABAFB23};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

The project can then be loaded normally in Monodevelop.

Comment: Just got this error and the solution still works! Thanks.

Comment: This does work for me, but the problem doesn't stay fixed.  After today's work, I saved, exited, then tried to reopen it, and got the same problem.  The solution works to fix it each time, but it's not necessarily a long-term answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error with the build-in mono dev of last few version of Unity on OSX.

To solve it: Add-in manager -> Language bindings -> Enable C# binding

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar issue using Visual Studio for MacOS. Running a `git diff` on the `.csproj` revealed some stray non-printable Unicode characters had been inserted at the beginning of the file:

`<U+FEFF><U+FEFF><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

I resolved the issue by manually deleting and retyping the `<?xml` portion.